# TwelveMonkeys 3.1.1 || 3.1.2 not working with maven-dependency-plugin

Tags: java, maven-dependency-plugin, twelvemonkeys

I am trying to use [TwelveMonkeys](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys) in my application to deal with thumbnail generation. Also, I am using `maven-dependency-plugin` to unpack all dependencies and create a FAT jar. Though, plugin work quite well in normal scenarios, but simply not working when used with maven-dependency-plugin. Here is my POM XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.prakhar</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <name>demo</name>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <organization>
        <!-- Used as the 'Vendor' for JNLP generation -->
        <name>Your Organisation</name>
    </organization>

    <properties>
        <slf4j.version>1.6.1</slf4j.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <!-- Get the dependencies jar files to a common place, for jar signing -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- <includeArtifactIds>commons-net,imageio-bmp,imageio-jpeg,imageio-tiff,imageio-pnm,imageio-psd,imageio-iff,imageio-pcx,imageio-pict,imageio-sgi,imageio-tga,imageio-icns,imageio-thumbsdb,imageio-core,imageio-metadata,common-lang,common-io,common-image</includeArtifactIds> -->
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>


    <dependencies>

        <!-- MigLayout -->



        <!-- Apache Commons -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging  -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Twelve Monkeys dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.twelvemonkeys.imageio</groupId>
            <artifactId>imageio-bmp</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.twelvemonkeys.imageio</groupId>
            <artifactId>imageio-jpeg</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.twelvemonkeys.imageio</groupId>
            <artifactId>imageio-tiff</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.twelvemonkeys.imageio</groupId>
            <artifactId>imageio-pnm</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.twelvemonkeys.imageio</groupId>
            <artifactId>imageio-psd</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.twelvemonkeys.imageio</groupId>
            <artifactId>imageio-iff</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.twelvemonkeys.imageio</groupId>
            <artifactId>imageio-pcx</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.twelvemonkeys.imageio</groupId>
            <artifactId>imageio-pict</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.twelvemonkeys.imageio</groupId>
            <artifactId>imageio-sgi</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.twelvemonkeys.imageio</groupId>
            <artifactId>imageio-tga</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.twelvemonkeys.imageio</groupId>
            <artifactId>imageio-icns</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.twelvemonkeys.imageio</groupId>
            <artifactId>imageio-thumbsdb</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

And, here is my function:

```
private static void convertToJpg(File file) {
    try {
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);

        int width = 300, height = 200; // new width/height

        BufferedImageOp resampler = new ResampleOp(width, height, ResampleOp.FILTER_LANCZOS); // A good default filter, see class documentation for more info
        BufferedImage thumbnailImg = resampler.filter(image, null);

        FileImageOutputStream fios = new FileImageOutputStream(new File(file.getAbsolutePath() + ".png"));

        if (!ImageIO.write(thumbnailImg, "PNG", fios)) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: Unable to convert image " + file.getAbsolutePath());
        } else {
            System.out.println("SUCCESS: Image " + file.getAbsolutePath() + ".png converted successfully");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here is the exception I am getting:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Input == null
    at com.twelvemonkeys.image.ResampleOp.filter(Unknown Source)
```

If anybody have any idea of how might be solved, please state.

Comment: What kind of file are you trying to read? The error message suggests you have no reader plugin for the file format. I don't know exactly how the fat-jar plugin works, but I know that each `imageio-xxx.jar` plugin contains images under `META-INF/services/` with the same name. *These needs to be merged somehow.* If they are overwritten, the plugins will not be registered.

Comment: @myself: There's a typo in the comment above. ;-) It should say "*each `imageio-xxx.jar` plugin contains **resources** under `META-INF/services/` with the same name*". That is, there are multiple `META-INF/services/javax.imageio.spi.ImageReaderSpi` (and other) resources, that needs to be merged into a single resource. I'm not sure how the Maven plugin handles that.

Comment: The Maven Shade plugin seems to provide a solution for this, see Resource transformers, especially the [ServicesResourceTransformer](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/resource-transformers.html#ServicesResourceTransformer).

Comment: @haraldK, Thank you very much for pointing me towards `META-INF/services/` folder. Shade plugin did hit the spot. I replaced it with  legacy `maven-dependency-plugin`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To sum it up, for future readers, the problem is that each ImageIO plugin JAR contains multiple resources under `META-INF/services`. These resources are needed for automatic discovery of the ImageIO plugins. They are:

```
META-INF/services/javax.imageio.spi.ImageReaderSpi
META-INF/services/javax.imageio.spi.ImageWriterSpi
META-INF/services/javax.imageio.spi.ImageInpuStreamSpi
META-INF/services/javax.imageio.spi.ImageOutputStreamSpi
```

There might be more, but these are not used by TwelveMonkeys.

For the interested you can read more about the [Service Provider Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/SPI-intro.html) mechanism and the [`ServiceRegistry`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/spi/ServiceRegistry.html) class in particular.

When you unpack all the JAR files into a single folder, these will be overwritten for each JAR. Instead, the resources with the same name needs to be merged into a new, single resource.

The [Maven Shade plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/index.html) provides a solution for this, see Resource transformers, especially the [ServicesResourceTransformer](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/resource-transformers.html#ServicesResourceTransformer).

Comment: My quick and temporary solution was to add this line `com.twelvemonkeys.imageio.plugins.pnm.PNMImageReaderSpi` to `<jar>/META-INF/services/javax.imageio.spi.ImageReaderSpi` since I only needed to read PNM/PGM files. It worked well for submitting my assignment!